# MSSQL LIKE operator with Node.js SQL query

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sql-server, database

I am trying to get data even when "naziv" query value is not an exact match with the value from the table but just a similar one.

```
const sqlConfig = require("../config/ms.config")

exports.data = async (req, res) => {

    const { sifart, naziv, uempl, idfirma } = req.query

    try {

            await sql.connect(sqlConfig.sqlConfig)
            var tableData = await sql.query(' SELECT sifart,naziv,uempl,idfirma FROM [dbo].[artikli] WHERE (sifart = '+ sifart +' OR '+ sifart +' IS NULL) AND (naziv LIKE '+ naziv +' OR '+ naziv +' IS NULL) AND (uempl = '+ uempl +' OR '+ uempl +' IS NULL) AND (idfirma = '+ idfirma +' OR '+ idfirma +' IS NULL) ')
            var result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tableData))
            console.log(result.recordset)
            res.status(200).send(result.recordset)

        } catch (err) {
            res.status(404).send({message: "Cannot find, please try something else!"});
            console.log(err)
        }

}
```

Comment: **WARNING:** Your code is **dangerous**. It is wide open to SQL injection attacks. Always, *always, **always*** parametrise your code. [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](//stackoverflow.com/q/7505808)

Comment: As you are building the query in your code just omit null args from the WHERE clause.

Comment: @Serg I can't do that because of my React page render on frontend

Comment: This isn't just dangerous, it's also incorrect as quotes `'` are missing. Another reason to use parameters

Answer (score 0):

Basically in LIKE operator you have to specify % based on your need. Description is [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

```
var tableData = await sql.query(' SELECT sifart,naziv,uempl,idfirma FROM [dbo].[artikli] WHERE (sifart = '+ sifart +' OR '+ sifart +' IS NULL) AND (naziv LIKE '%+ naziv +%' OR '%+ naziv +%' IS NULL) AND (uempl = '+ uempl +' OR '+ uempl +' IS NULL) AND (idfirma = '+ idfirma +' OR '+ idfirma +' IS NULL) ')
```

This will work :)